# How do you connect to postgres running in a Docker container on OSx?

Tags: macos, postgresql, docker

I have postgres running in a Docker container on OSx. At first I tried connecting to it locally. I started the container with:

```
docker run -i -d -h localhost -p 5432:5432 --name some-postgres -t my-postgres:9.6 postgres
```

After some digging, I found out that you cannot connect to it over `localhost` on OSx, you need to connect to the ip address that docker is using internally. So I used `docker-machine` to create a vm at `192.168.99.100:2376`. However, I am still unable to connect to postgres over `192.168.99.100:5432`. What am I missing? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Docker for Mac, then it should work on `localhost` as is: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/#use-cases-and-workarounds

Comment: So I do have Docker for Mac, but connecting to `localhost` doesn't work...however, after looking through virtualbox, I found that the `docker-machine ip` was returning `192.168.99.100`, but I was actually just able to connect to `192.168.99.1`. What do you think is going on here?

Comment: this ended up working, the problem was there was another postgres running on localhost already :|

Answer (score 3):

Here's a working example of how to launch Postgres using Docker for Mac. It's similar to your example.

Note that this is *not* docker-machine, so maybe networking works differently.

```bash
docker run --rm -it \
-p 5432:5432 \
-e POSTGRES_USER=user-ms \
-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=12345 \
postgres
```

I tried establishing connections to it from the Docker host…

Localhost worked:

```bash
psql --user user-ms -h localhost
```

And the local IP address worked also:

```bash
psql --user user-ms -h "$(ifconfig \
| grep -E "([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}" \
| grep -v 127.0.0.1 \
| awk '{ print $2 }' \
| cut -f2 -d: \
| head -n1)"
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. When I try to connect to the db, it says `role "user-ms" does not exist`